# Being attacked with one unit

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm playing Clash of Clans, Silver League 1, and I've been seeing some attacks on me by players who commit one unit and then surrender, giving me a whole stack of trophies for nothing. At first I thought it was just someone who waited a bit too long before deciding not to attack but it seems to be a bit too frequent for that.

Is there some bizarre strategy going on here, or what is it?

Comment: When I used to play this game I would do exactly what you described simply to be in the lower ranks. I would drop one troop and end battle to cheaply do it. The benefits of this were not being attacked as often because the lower ranks did not have players well off enough to attack me, and resource boosting. The resources in the lower leagues can be easy to come by from inactive players whom just about always have full resource containers.

Comment: Did my answer address everything you wanted to know, or is there anything I can do to improve it? If it addressed everything, could you click the check mark on it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 3 reasons this may be happening, lionwaffles and lord Jorge touched on 2 of them.

1. They may have accidently dropped a troop when trying to click next or end battle.

The reason they would then end the battle is possibly because they don't want to waste their troops trying to get the amount of loot you have, or they don't think their troops are strong enough to successfully attack you. In both cases they decided losing trophies was better than wasting troops.

2. They may be actively trying to drop trophies.

To expand on why someone would want to drop trophies, they may have pushed trophies to get to a certain league or trophy count for a gem reward and wish to return to their lower league, they may be approaching the trophy count to get promoted to the next league and want to drop trophies to remain in their current league, they may want to drop to a lower league to find easier bases (generally speaking the higher the trophy level, the stronger the bases are), or they may want to drop trophies to protect loot (at higher trophies people will generally attack with stronger armies).

3. They may have actually been trying to raid your base and accidently clicked end battle when trying to switch or deploy troops.

Comment: Really, the most important part of this answer is the second reason. Reasons 1 and 3 almost never happen.

Comment: 3 is like invalid since there is a pop-up that ensures that you click yes or no to actually surrender

Comment: @PythonMaster ive seen people accidentally end battles that way before. if you are tapping quickly, there is a chance that you may accidentally click surrender and ok before you notice what you did

Answer (score 0):

this is actually an strategy, in the latest patch the old and non-active villages had their TH outside the base, and destroying the TH no longer grants a shield, so the biggest pool of non-active villages were deep in bronze lueague, at least it was like that for two o three weeks after the big update.

Comment: So it's a strategy to get down to the league where the pool of unprotected villages are?

Comment: It's not clear what the strategy is, and I seriously question there is one other than simply dropping trophies to make it less likely your base gets streamrolled by more advanced players.

Comment: The idea is to farm with barbarian and archres, so a ot of people is going down for that, just like we used to farm before the update, that is the main reason...

Answer (score -2):

No it is not a strategy. It has happened to me as well. Sometimes people touch the screen by accident which deploys the troop.

Comment: There is certainly a reason for a player to intentionally drop a single unit and surrender immediately.